# Debug logs are not generated for Sandboxed container

Tags: gvisor

I am trying to sandbox a simple docker container is running Unary gRPC server application.

following code sandboxes and runs the docker container for me:

```
  docker run --runtime=runsc  -d -p 50051:50051/tcp docker_image
```

I have enabled the debug logs but I don't see any debug logs getting generated.

Following command ran successfully

```
$ docker run --runtime=runsc -it ubuntu dmesg
```

I have ensured that the debug logs and systemcall logs are enabled by adding runtimeArgs to the docker daemon file present in */etc/docker/daemon.json*

```
{
"runtimes": {
    "runsc": {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin/runsc",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--debug-log=/tmp/runsc/",
            "--debug",
            "--strace"
        ]
   }
}
```

}

I do not see any stack traces after running

```
sudo runsc --root /var/run/docker/runtime-runsc/moby debug --stacks container-id
```

No files are generated at the specified log location in */tmp/runsc/*

I have tried the gVisor [documentation](https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/debugging/) but I do not understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

so I found the solution to my question. Inorder to run gVisor in debug mode, we need to specify runtime as rubsc-debug.

- Normal Mode

  --runtime=runsc
- Debug Mode

  --runtime=runsc-debug

following command worked for me

```
docker run --runtime=runsc-debug  -d -p 50051:50051/tcp docker_image
```